# Spring Data JPA OneToMany Parent recursively find if any Children is the Parent

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

This is my entity:

```java
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table()
@Audited
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid-gen", strategy = "uuid2")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid-gen")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "uuid")
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_grouping", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable = false)
    private Group grouping;
}
```

That means one Group can have one Grouping.
For example, we can have the five following registers:

```
Group 1 - Sweet Box
Group 2 - Candy Paper
Group 3 - Gum Paper
Group 4 - Candy
Group 5 - Gum
```

And we'll have the following connections between groups:

```
Sweet Box -> Candy Paper -> Candy
Sweet Box -> Gum Paper -> Gum
```

Where "Sweet Box" is the parent of Candy Paper and Gum Paper.

If the user try to connect "Sweet Box" with some of his childrens, It need to be validated, like:

```
Sweet Box -> Candy Paper -> Sweet Box.
```

The parent cannot be children of some of his childrens or himself. But can have an Infinite cascade of parents.

So is there anyway to do this in a single shot? Tried checking resursively but didn't find a way in JPA.